# Is BitCoin Mining Basically a Game? Do the Solved Math Equations do Anything?

Tags: bitcoind

So I've been trying to learn about bitcoin, I'm a kid. It is really confusing. Is BitCoin basically a game since you solve math equations for money? And also, do the math equations do anything or are they just random and because you solve them, you get a reward for your intelligence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its kinda like solving really hard math equations.

Mostly done by specificaly made machines like this one:
[Antminer S9](https://shop.bitmain.com/market.htm?name=antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner)

But this video explains it all https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmOzih6I1zs

Answer (score 0):

The solving process is called "mining". It's useful to make creating blocks with transactions **hard** and that makes it hard to spend Bitcoins that were already spent.